My C program that works with serial port hangs on read if ran for the second time
I am using Cygwin environment to build my program. Also I use the termius library. Essentially, the program opens the serial port:
fuart = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);

Then its workflow involves writing to the serial port this way:
write(fuart, str, xlen);

As well as reading from it:
ln = read(fuart, buff, n);

And at the end:
tcflush(fuart,TCIOFLUSH);
close(fuart);
sleep(2); //just in case

When I run the program for the first time it works great, however when launched subsequently with same input data and whatnot, it will hang on read. If I disable the COM port in Windows device manager and re-enable it, then everything goes fine on the next run.
I thought maybe my program doesn't properly close the port due to compatability issues and it remains locked, however other terminal software such as teraterm could open it, more interestingly, if I try to run my program for the second time and it hangs, I can see the data it wrote to the serial port after I forcibly close it via task manager and open 3rd party terminal software. So seems like my C program cannot properly handle closing of the COM port (or perhaps flushing/releasing the read buffer, since it hangs on the read operation) and this is not an OS or platform issue. Note that during its work my program successfully  reads and writes to the port several times (but again only during the first run after which I have to disable-enable the device or open another terminal software).
For reference, the device I communicate with is an USB modem.
I tried searching for the answer but had little luck, other than finding advise to close the port, which I already do.I have seen someone was in the same boat and they used the enable-disable trick, but like I said my research revealed that other terminal programs do not have this bug and they even help to release the COM port. I even found a software that uses Cygwin runtime, namely mobastorm, and it doesn't suffer from this problem.

Does your true code check the return values of all the various I/O calls?  So far, the small code samples do not.  Try that first.  Note: best to post a [mcve].

Your fixation on "closing of the COM port" and concern about the "serial port or its buffers aren't released" are misplaced. All the resources that your program acquired will be released by the OS when your program terminates. You can verify that by deleting the close() statement(s) from your program; you can then expect no difference in program (mis)behavior. Different behavior on program startup is more often an indication of improper/incomplete initialization (which you neglect to describe in any detail).

@blackgreen - Why was the answer by TGDEV deleted? That post offered salient information that the OP seem to be unaware of. IMO that post offered more practical information that the second answer.

@awdust, improper initialization would likely cause the code to fail on the first run.

"improper initialization would likely cause the code to fail on the first run." - Maybe. But I'm also referring to an incomplete initialization, which will result in (re-)using the existing termios configuration (left by the previous program). When your program does not perform a complete termios configuration to its requirements, then you leave it to chance. That can cause an unreliable program, just like you seem to have.

To narrow down the issue, because it hangs on read() you could set the file descriptor for the serial port in none-block mode.
You can do this with the flag O_NDELAY or O_NONBLOCK.
fd_uart = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC | O_NONBLOCK);

I suggest before you call read() to check if there are bytes available for reading. You can do this with a I/O control command. If there are no bytes available or lesser bytes which you want to read, read() hangs, if the file descriptor is in block mode.
Sample for POSIX systems:
#include <ioctl.h>

int ret;
int bytes;

ret = ioctl(fd_uart, FIONREAD, &bytes);

Sample for Windows only:
#include <Windows.h>

int ret;
int bytes;
COMSTAT comst;
DWORD dwerr;

ret = ClearCommError(handle_uart, &dwerr, &comst);
bytes = (int) comst.cbInQue;

The number of bytes which are available for reading are stored in the variable bytes.
Another suggestion from me to set the serial port in raw mode:
#include <termios.h>

struct termios options;

/* Set raw input mode */
options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
/* Enable receiver and set local mode */
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
/* Set raw output mode */
options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
tcsetattr(fd_uart, TCSANOW, &options);


Thanks for your answer, I did what you suggested and traced the issue a bit further. Here's how it goes: on the first launch the program successfully runs all i/o operations; on the second launch it writes to the serial port, but as soon as it tries to read, there is 0 bytes of data, even though in reality the response is written by the device. I tried adding sleep()  - no result. Once I open any other terminal software I see the data written by my program and device response. So somehow the serial port or its buffers aren't released, even though I call close() and tcflush().

@CuriousUser Try to remove tcflush(). tcflush() discards all data in the file descriptor. So if you write something and then call tcflush() the data is lost and will not be send over the serial port. You can read this in the manual page from tcflush()

I called tcflush() before closing the port, anyways I tried to remove it and seen no change.

"Another suggestion from me to set the serial port in raw mode: ..." - The suggested code is half-baked. At least you're properly using bit operations, but they're performed on elements of an uninitialized structure. And the salient VMIN and VTIME values are left to chance (although your bad advice of non-blocking mode makes this irrelevant). Since the OP has not posted anything related to termios, you cannot nor should not assume anything. Suggesting such specific fixes to code you haven't seen is foolish.
